# Hg Repo with Git and Hg Remotes

Tags: git, mercurial

I am taking a class that has a read-only git repository. I want to clone this into an hg repo. However, since I can't push back to this repo, I want to push to a repo in bitbucket with my local changes, but still pull down any changes from the git repo. I know you can clone a git repo with hg-git, but I want everything to be hg except the read-only git remote for the class. Thanks!

Comment: Simply clone or push your repo to a remote mercurial repo and that's it. The remote you push to need not be a git one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have 2 paths defined in project's [.hgrc](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths)

Git's path will appear automatically, when you'll clone repo. HG's URL you have to add by hand

With up-to-date Mercurial you can have two slightly different configs (and resulting commands)

```
default = git+URL/OF/GIT
hg = URL/OF/HG
```

means using `hg pull` + `hg push hg`

```
default = git+URL/OF/GIT
default:pushurl = URL/OF/HG
```

means using plain `hg pull` + `hg push`, but push will happen anyway to Mercurial-repo